# CSS - Positioning navigation menu lists

Tags: html, css, list

HTML/CSS Novice here. Quick question. What's the best tool to position nav. lists? Margins? "position:"? I have ID'd the 2 (#top and #bottom) lists, but not quite sure what to use to position them correctly.

> What I have in mind -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/LitBZ.jpg

**UPDATE QUESTION -**

For some reason the spaces between the words won't come in exact equal measure with `"li"` width. Some need to be adjusted up to 10px if you want to get it perfect. Is there a way to add spaces(px) before and after individual words? I tried adding white spaces, but no avail.

http://jsfiddle.net/RE6Xk/11/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use an unordered list with list items that are floated and sized

[demo jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/DbppU/1/)

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="#">Nav 1</a></li>
  ...
</ul>
```

```
...
#nav li {
  float:left;
  width:240px;
  height:40px;
  line-height:40px;
  text-align:center;
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `tables` as you have 2 rows and 4 columns...

Answer (score 0):

I think that the distance between each element is the same in one line. Because of this, I prefer to use the same value of margin for each element.